# Is it possible to install xampp on a mobile device like a galaxy tab or ipad?

Tags: android, xampp, tablet

Was wondering if you can install xampp and notepad++ on a samsung galaxy tab 10.1 or an ipad?  have tried no luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for [Paw server](http://paw-android.fun2code.de/).

Paw server is a web server for android that also has a PHP plugin. For development there are many options available, just search [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=PHP%20editor&c=apps).

Answer (score 3):

I use BitWeb server which is sorta the same thing but with lighttpd instead of apache. I have even gotten a Zend implementation to work under it.

Comment: I have since converted to using Server Ultimate Pro as it gives you multiple servers in a single app.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend Palapa Server.. Mysql, Php and works great.. free, and very customizable.